# Reading XML files in R: UTF-8 and Umlaut

Tags: xml, r, utf-8, import

I want to import some xml file with some german text including umlauts (like ä, ö, ü, &, ").
But somehow i cant get a proper import.
Im using RStudio and the XML Package, here is what i do:
Example XML-File (edited example from wikipedia):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<verzeichnis>
<titel>Wikipedia Städteverzeichnis</titel>
<eintrag>
<stichwort>Genf</stichwort>
<eintragstext>Genf ist der Sitz von ä ü ö &amp;...</eintragstext>
</eintrag>
</verzeichnis>
```

Import of XML File

```
doc <- xmlParse('data/example.xml', useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

Result

```
> doc
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<verzeichnis>
  <titel>Wikipedia StÃ¤dteverzeichnis</titel>
  <eintrag>
    <stichwort>Genf</stichwort>
   <eintragstext>Genf ist der Sitz von Ã¤ Ã¼ Ã¶ &amp;...</eintragstext>
  </eintrag>
</verzeichnis>
```

So obviously the umlauts are not imported correctly, how do i fix it?

Comment: what version of R are you using? I'm using 3.0.2 on my Mac and this is working fine

Comment: Im using RStudio with R 3.1.2 (64 bit Windows)

Comment: updated my answer. you should be able to set the locale as windows defaults to non utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like windows may not use UTF-8 by default, [as mentioned in this article](http://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/comment-page-1/). There are various solutions in there for writing out to binary instead.

However, have you tried setting your system locale?

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale="en_US.UTF-8")
```

I managed to "break" it by setting the locale to an ISO8859-1 locale like "fi_FI.ISO8859-1"

**EDIT**

I installed the Windows version of R 3.1.2 to replicate this, and sure enough, it is same as you posted. I tried the following, and although the output on the R console doesn't look correct the output to the file is correct

```
> Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale="German")
> [1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
> doc <- xmlParse("c:/Users/Mark/german.xml")
> saveXML(doc, "c:/Users/Mark/german-2.xml")
```

The file is written as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<verzeichnis><titel>Wikipedia Städteverzeichnis</titel><eintrag><stichwort>Genf</stichwort><eintragstext>Genf ist der Sitz von ä ü ö &amp;...</eintragstext></eintrag></verzeichnis>"
```

so it appears to write correctly.

Comment: wont work, 
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored , same with "de_DE.UTF-8", Sys.getlocale() gives:
"LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252", Edit: it actually looks like German_Germany.1252 and de_DE.UTF-8 are the same: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales

Comment: another update to my answer. installed windows version and set the system locale to "German", and it writes to the file correctly

Comment: mmh thats weird, i could reproduce this though, it looks like it writes correctly, still i cant work with the xml file properly in rstudio, for example ö is recognised as "Ã¶" and counts as 2 characters ... when i actually need r to recognize it as "ö" and 1 character. ("Ã¶" =="ö" will give me FALSE)

Comment: well i found a work around, i take the string i need and do s <- as.character(s) and Encoding(s) <- "UTF-8" and then it shows it properly and i can work with it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: glad i could help. i moved all dev off windows many years ago because of encoding issues!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, this was the solution that worked for me:

```
linkToXmlFile <- "<yourPath>"

library(XML)

data <- xmlParse(linkToXmlFile, encoding="UTF-8")
xmlDataFrame <- xmlToDataFrame(data)
```

I used Windows 10 and the XML was stored in an UTF-8 textfile.